# pytorch: the dropout layer after LayerNorm, There are some magical phenomena

Tags: nlp, pytorch, normalization, text-classification, dropout

When I add a dropout layer after LayerNorm，the validation set loss reduction at 1.5 epoch firstly，then the loss Substantially increase，and the acc becomes 0; when I remove the dropout layer, it works; when I remove the layernorm, it changes , not zero, but results was very poor.

the model code:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        if config.embedding_pretrained is not None:
            #self.embedding = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(config.embedding_pretrained, freeze=False)
            self.embedding = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(torch.FloatTensor(config.embedding_pretrained.vectors), freeze=False)
        else:
            self.embedding = nn.Embedding(config.n_vocab, config.embed, padding_idx=config.n_vocab - 1)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(config.embed, config.hidden_size, config.num_layers,
                            bidirectional=True, batch_first=True, dropout=config.dropout)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(config.pad_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size * 2 + config.embed, config.num_classes)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)
        
        self.ln_emb = nn.LayerNorm(config.embed)
        self.ln_lstm = nn.LayerNorm(config.hidden_size * 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x, _ = x
        embed = self.embedding(x)  # [batch_size, seq_len, embeding]
        embed = self.ln_emb(embed)
        out, _ = self.lstm(embed)
        out = self.ln_lstm(out)

        out = torch.cat((embed, out), 2)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        #out = F.relu(out)
        out = out.permute(0, 2, 1)
        out = self.maxpool(out).squeeze()
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

- the acc tensorboard:

[image: the acc curve]

- the loss tensorboard:

[image: the loss curve]

Comment: Stupid question but do you put your model in eval mode during validation to disable dropout and layernorm?

Comment: yes, I use "model.eval()" during running validation set, and the acc in validation set increased to 0.6，then it droped rapidly to 0.0

Comment: Hard to say without being able to try different configurations and architecture but from what I see in your code, you apply dropout in the recurrent layers, then afterwards on the concatenated layers, without much steps in between. Additionally, you should take into account that the dropout operation in PT is not only setting some neurons to 0 but also rescaling to take into account the loss of energy. Your best bet is experimentation though